# Records not getting updated when PreUpdate listener is used in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am  using preupdate event listener concept in my database implemention.

When I am adding listener as below the contenst in DB not getting updated.

```
<property name="eventListeners">
  <map>
    <entry key="post-load">
      <list>
        <ref local="cisAuditLoadEventListener" />
      </list>
    </entry>
    <entry key="pre-update">
      <list>
        <ref local="cisAuditLoadEventListener" />
      </list>
    </entry>
</property>
```

When I remove this listener (pre-update), update working fine.

In this pre-update listener i am inserting some records in db like audit records. I am able to insert them. But unable to update the records i want.

Below is the method i am overriding in a class which implements PreUpdateEventListener.

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * org.hibernate.event.PreUpdateEventListener#onPreUpdate(org.hibernate.event
 * .PreUpdateEvent)
 */
 @Override
 public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event)
 {

    //insert data in db
 }
```

Can any one help me regarding this problem.

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you return `false` from that method. (i.e. the operation should not be vetoed)

Comment: @Narenda - was that the actual problem?

Comment: Yes. I am retrning true instead of false.